# Content Search Webpart Custom Image

Tags: content-search-web-part

I am using the content search webpart to show a list of Project sites using the template ID, I would like to have a custom image next to each project, currently it is showing the Project Site logo

[image]

What is the best way to have a custom image using the property mappings instead of the site Logo?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom display template. Here are some instructions on how to do it:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj945138.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396